# Android how can I get ShareActionProvider working on ImageButton click

Tags: android, oncreate, shareactionprovider

I am working on a project that requires that the ShareAction menu be opened on an Onclick method and I can not seem to get it to work. First of I have the ShareAction menu working but only in the settings menu and this is; is what I have when I try to apply that to ImageButton Onclick method

```
// This is inside the Oncreate Method

share= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.share);
        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ShareActionProvider nn= new ShareActionProvider(Login.this);
                Intent ShareIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                ShareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                ShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                ShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text To share");
               nn.setShareIntent(ShareIntent);
            }
        });
```

The code above does not work it does not give any errors or nothing. I have that same code working using the settings menu and doing the following
Menu for activity

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".Login">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="200" android:icon="@drawable/overflow" app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_share" android:title="@string/action_share" android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        />

</menu>
```

then simply add it to the menu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
    MenuItem shareItem= menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

    ShareActionProvider  mShare= (ShareActionProvider)shareItem.getActionProvider();
   Intent ShareIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    ShareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    ShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    ShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text To share");
    mShare.setShareIntent(ShareIntent);
    return true;
}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong that is not letting the menu open in Oncreate?

Answer (score 1):

> I am working on a project that requires that the ShareAction menu be opened on an Onclick method and I can not seem to get it to work

This does not make much sense. `ShareActionProvider` is an action bar item. It has its own "button" to allow the user to share content, based on a configured `Intent` indicating what sort of sharing is to be done (e.g., MIME type).

So, there are three possibilities here, that I can see:

1. Just use the `ShareActionProvider` and get rid of this `ImageButton`.
2. Get rid of the `ShareActionProvider`, and do something else to show a list of sharing actions in `onClick()` of the `ImageButton`. For example, you could wrap the `Intent` in `Intent.createChooser()` and call `startActivity()` on that `Intent` from `onClick()` -- if there are two or more activities that match the `Intent`, the user will get the chooser "menu".
3. Fork `ShareActionProvider` to have it expose some sort of `open()` method that allows you to activate it from `onClick()` of your `ImageButton`. I cannot envision a situation in which this makes any sense (why would clicking a button over here pop open a drop-down menu over there?).

Comment: Oh ok perfect thanks for letting me know, I am new to this. I will work on the second option as I need users to shared individual posts.